# Upgrading Mongo from 4.2 to 4.4 can't find configuration file

Tags: mongodb, minikube

I have an up and running application that uses Mongo 4.2, set up with Minikube.

I was initializing the replicaset with `rs.initiate()` and everything worked correctly. Now after the upgrade to 4.4, I'm getting the following error:

`msg":"User assertion","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: no replset config has been received","file":"src/mongo/db/repl/repl_set_get_status_cmd.cpp","line":56}}`

So I tried adding some more info on the config of the initialization:

```
rs.initiate({
                "_id" : "myapp",
                "members" : [
                    {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "localhost:27017",
                        "priority" : 1
                    }
                ]
            });
```

But the result is the same. Could it be that the configuration has to be set up in a different way from 4.4 on?

My replicaset, in this local setup for development, has always consisted on just one node, could it be the problem, maybe?

Comment: Did you set `replication.replSetName` in the config file?

Comment: I'm starting this with the command line, where I have this argument `--replSet myapp`

Comment: When you install MongoDB then usually it installs also a service, i.e. mongod starts automatically at boot time. The default config file does not configure a Replica Set. Verify the running instance.

Comment: Where can I find that configuration file? I'm not configurating it myself, I'm just passing the arguments though the command line.

Comment: What do you start with `--replSet myap`? The `mongod` or the mongo shell?

Comment: That's in my docker-compose. The image is mongo:4.4 and the replSet is part of the command line of that service